# How do we get the best signal in Bahamas

Tags: cellular-data, cellular

We live on a sailboat and are headed to the Bahamas for the winter. Getting good phone (and data would be great!) coverage is important but we don’t have a satellite phone budget. Space X might be possible. SIM cards are easy but what are THE FACTS about boosters, antennas, etc.?